# Own Broadcastreceiver didn't receive simulated SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm currently working on a project where I analyze the SMS_RECEIVED-Flow.

According to the article [1] I simulated the SMS_RECEIVED-Broadcast with an explicit call to the service: `com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService`.

The problem is, that the Android-Emulator and my Nexus do forward
the generated BroadcastReceiver to the default SMS-App only and I do not know why.

I tried to catch the Broadcast with an statically registered receiver in another App and with an dynamically registered receiver (all receiver registered with the highest priority and the correct intent-filter). Both methods work fine with a normal SMS, but not with my simulated one.

So the question is, does anybody know how the SMS-Receive mechanism work and why my program won't receive any broadcasts.

[1] http://blog.dev001.net/post/14085892020/android-generate-incoming-sms-from-within-your-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmsRecieverService is part of default messaging app, so if you explicitly call this service, the broadcast will reach only that app. Since the SMS_RECIEVED broadcast is a protected broadcast , your app cannot broadcast it.

One way is to change the name of the broadcast in both simulator and your app.

Comment: Thx,
I knew that the SMS_RECEIVED broadcast is protected but I hoped that there is a workaround to simulate the receiving-behavior, because of the fact that after a while Handcent receives the simulated sms too (It seems that Handcent crashes and after reopening it will receive the Sms).
... I think that Handcent receives the Sms from the content provider or so.

Comment: if you have a custom rom you can sign your app with platform signature, then you will be able t o broadcast.